# using an array with fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, fields-for

How can I iterate through an array of objects (all the same model) using fields_for ?
The array contains objects created by the current_user.

I currently have:

```
<%= f.fields_for :descriptionsbyuser do |description_form| %>
<p class="fields">
    <%= description_form.text_area :entry, :rows => 3 %>
    <%= description_form.link_to_remove "Remove this description" %>
    <%= description_form.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

But I want to replace the :descriptionsbyuser with an array I created in my controller - @descriptionsFromCurrentUser

This is also inside Ryan Bate's "nested_form_for"

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Adam

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[Docs for `fields_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for) clearly shows you the way of using arrays:

> Or a collection to be used:
>
> ```
> <%= form_for @person do |person_form| %>
>   ...
>   <%= person_form.fields_for :projects, @active_projects do |project_fields| %>
>     Name: <%= project_fields.text_field :name %>
>   <% end %>
>   ...
> <% end %>
> ```

`@active_projects` here is your array.

Comment: This isn't working for me. I'm getting something like `undefined method 'name' for #<Array:0xaedada0>`.

Comment: @Ajedi32 et al => Your model needs to implement a setter for the collection attributes. See answer from barelyknown.

Answer (score 42):

To use a collection for `fields_for` and have it work the way that you expect, the model needs accept nested attributes for the collection. If the collection is an `ActiveRecord` one-to-many relationship, use the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` class macro. If the collection is not an `ActiveRecord` one-to-many relationship, you'll need to implement a collection getter and a collection attributes setter.

If it is an `ActiveRecord` relationship:

```
class Person
  has_many :projects

  # this creates the projects_attributes= method
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :projects
end
```

If it is a non-`ActiveRecord` relationship:

```
class Person
  def projects
    ...
  end

  def projects_attributes=(attributes)
    ...
  end
end
```

Either way, the form is the same:

```
<%= form_for @person do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.fields_for :projects, @active_projects do |f| %>
    Name: <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <% end %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: +1 for non-ActiveRecord implementation details. Somehow my eye refused to see what was clearly explained in the docs ...

Answer (score 8):

i found this to be the cleanest way
if you are working with straight data and want to send back an array without using any of these @objects

```
<%= form_for :team do |t| %>
  <%= t.fields_for 'people[]', [] do |p| %>
    First Name: <%= p.text_field :first_name %>
    Last Name: <%= p.text_field :last_name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

your params data should return like this

```
"team" => {
  "people" => [
    {"first_name" => "Michael", "last_name" => "Jordan"},
    {"first_name" => "Steve", "last_name" => "Jobs"},
    {"first_name" => "Barack", "last_name" => "Obama"}
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 5):

An addition to barelyknown's answer (wasn't able to add as a comment due to reputation points) -

For the non-activerecord case, I also had to define `persisted?` in my class in addition to `*_attributes=(attributes)`.